# Number of tiles inside a region of a hyperbolic tiling

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the Poincare disc model of hyperbolic geometry with $\{p,q\}$ tiling on it.
In this, [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwirnoza2Ob7AhUHG4gKHd4RA48QFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2FS0893965903800526%2Fpdf%3Fmd5%3D00faf8e7ad63b0636650206c652fd333%26pid%3D1-s2.0-S0893965903800526-main.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2hcgLkh7j2tikt04q5plNb) authors calculated the number of tiles on any circular region centered at a vertex or barycenter of a tile.
This motivates to ask the number of tiles in a polygonal region bounded by finitely many geodesics. Suppose the lengths of the sides of the polygon are $l_1,l_2,\cdots,l_n$. Then what will be the number of tiles which intersects the polygon?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: If rather than lengths you use angles, then there is a definitive answer using the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for your comment. Can we relate lengths with angles somehow?

Comment: Nope. If you fix a side length $L$ for a rectangle then, in the hyperbolic plane just as in the Euclidean plane, area is maximized in a square of side length $L$ and equal angles, but area approaches zero in flatter and flatter rhombuses of side length $L$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Here angle sum is changing. But if we fix the angle sum of the polygon then can we describe the area in terms of side lengths?

Comment: Well, assuming you are fixing $n$ (the number of sides) and the angle sum, then from the Gauss-Bonnet theorem it follows that the area is determined, *without any reference* to side lengths whatsoever.

Comment: @LeeMosher yes that i understood. But i want to find out possible polygons having one fixed angle sum and a fixed number of sides, with possibly different side lengths.

Comment: Well, in that case it sounds like what you "want to find out", as expressed in your latest comment, is not really the same as what you asked in your post: having fixed the angle sum and the number of sides, the area of the polygon is determined, hence the number of tiles in that polygon is determined, without reference to side lengths whatsoever.

Comment: So at this stage I would say that what you want to ask is not very clearly expressed in your post itself.